# Sitecore ContentSearch by field and relevance

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I'm using Sitecore 8 MVC .net 4.5. I have boolean field Is Sponsored and I need to order all items such as first with field Is Sponsored = true and by relevance. I found if I add order by Is_Sponsored I'm losing relevance order. So my question is: is there a way to include relevance in existing ordering?

Comment: Just a hint for possible close voters: SiteCore is a high-end CMS and these type of questions can only be asked by or are useful for developers, not for normal users. Migration to Superuser.com is not correct. See also [this MSO post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291566/how-to-report-invalid-downvotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the above method will work fine if you have only a limited amount of documents as you must read all documents from the index.

You can sort by the field SCORE to sort by the sort - so your sort order would be isSponsered, SCORE. This should work as far as I remember - but I have not validated it.

else - more to solr and you will have a number of options to solve this.

Comment: Thank you, I will try your solution first. I forgot to write that I have also requirement for pagging so it will be good if this order is working. Also above solution from Mark is my B plan but it looks to complicate to implement with pagging.

Comment: Also Klaus do you know how Linq query should looks like with Score field in order?

Answer (score 1):

You could skip the boolean check in your query and run a regular query with the right relevance order coming back. Then filter down that result set by the boolean value into two separate collections.

```
var results = queryable.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

Then:

```
var sponsored = results.Where(i => i.IsSponsored);

var notSponsored = results.Where(i => !i.IsSponsored);
```

Then join the collections.

Comment: Thank you Mark, your solution is my B plan because it looks complicate to implement with pagging. Forgot to write that I have pagging requirement so in this case I should get all Sponsored first with the relevance order and if there is no enought items add no sponsored in list.

Comment: Ok good to know, I wasn't aware of the paging need. Next time make sure you add that to the question :-)